# Bash osascript(AppleScript) in mac terminal, run multiple commands sequentially

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, osascript

I am trying to create a bash .sh script file that uses osascript to open 1 new terminal window/tab and then runs 2 commands "cd fs" and than "gulp" (both in the same window/tab)

This is what I am trying and it runs the second command (do script "gulp") in another (third) window/tab, not the second one that was opened.

`osascript -e '
  tell application "Terminal"
    do script "cd fs"
    do script "gulp"
  end tell'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to find the answer I was looking for

`osascript -e "
  tell application \"Terminal\"
    set currentTab to do script \"cd $(pwd)\"
    delay 2
    do script \"gulp env --env int\" in currentTab
    delay 5
    do script \"gulp\" in currentTab
    delay 30
  end tell"`